# Symbol not equal to Symbol

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a symbol that I pass into a function call like this in my controller:

```
set(:value, 1)
```

The function is in a helper function that more or less works like this

```
def set(where, what)
  session[:a][where] = what
end
def get(where)
  return session[:a][where]
end
```

I use this same symbol in my view in another function that should grab the same value:

```
get(:value)
```

And by debugging I have found that I end up checking 2 values in my hash table.
My get looks to work fine, but when I try and call the get from my view, my hash tries to find a value, but with single quotes around it.  I have tried a bunch of stuff to see what is going on, changing the values to be hard coded into the function is not helping, however, replacing the symbol with a string is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your symbols are stringified (during session serialization). To avoid that, stringify them preemptively!

```
def set(where, what)
  session[:a][where.to_s] = what
end
def get(where)
  return session[:a][where.to_s]
end
```

Comment: I figured that using symbols would avoid having to use strings.  But this is working, so perhaps I don't understand how symbols actually work.

Comment: @Tormyst: nah, I think you're on the right path. The problem here is that symbols don't work _everywhere_. Symbol is very much not a thing if we step outside of ruby. Say, we want to store our data to disk.

Comment: @Tormyst: don't forget to accept helpful answers. :)

Comment: Nearly forgot.  It would not let me tag it as right until a few minutes had passed.  Turns out, you were just too quick with the answer.